# ExcelVBA issues with IF else statement

Tags: excel, vba, macos

i am new to excel VBA
i am currently working on a mapping using excel vba. the concept is if i click on cell c6 it colors the various cell boxes applicable to it same goes to cell C7. Both C6 and C7 have a common cell mapping which is cell E6 But now i noticed that when i click on Cell C6, this cell E6 doesnt show case its colour but when i click on C7 the colour on this cell E6 shows the color which means my C7 if else statement has overriden the C6 on that common cell E6 please how can i fix this so that when i click on them individually they return the color shows. 
Below is my code:

```
Sub AccessControl1()
Range("C6").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
Range("D13").Interior.Color = RGB(154, 205, 50)

Range("E6").Interior.Color = RGB(154, 205, 50)

Range("F6").Interior.Color = RGB(154, 205, 50)
Range("AC6").Interior.Color = RGB(154, 205, 50)
Range("BH6").Interior.Color = RGB(154, 205, 50)
Range("DL7").Interior.Color = RGB(154, 205, 50)
Range("DF9").Interior.Color = RGB(154, 205, 50)
Range("DF6").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 20, 147)
Range("DA7").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 20, 147)
Range("DB23").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 20, 147)
Range("DF212").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 20, 147)
Range("DA215").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 20, 147)

End Sub
Sub AccessControl2()
Range("C6").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Range("D13").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)

Range("E6").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)

Range("F6").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Range("AC6").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Range("BH6").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Range("DL7").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Range("DF9").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Range("DF6").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Range("DA7").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Range("DB23").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Range("DF212").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Range("DA215").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End Sub
Sub AccountManagement1()
Range("C7").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)

Range("E6").Interior.Color = RGB(154, 205, 50)

Range("AE13").Interior.Color = RGB(154, 205, 50)
Range("AF6").Interior.Color = RGB(154, 205, 50)
Range("AG13").Interior.Color = RGB(154, 205, 50)
Range("AI6").Interior.Color = RGB(154, 205, 50)
Range("AJ13").Interior.Color = RGB(154, 205, 50)
Range("DA189").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 20, 147)
Range("DC195").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 20, 147)
Range("DA192").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 20, 147)
End Sub
Sub AccountManagement2()
Range("C7").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)

Range("AE13").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Range("AF6").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)

Range("E6").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)

Range("AG13").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Range("AI6").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Range("AJ13").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Range("DA189").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Range("DC195").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Range("DA192").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
If Target.Address = "$C$6" Then
    Call AccessControl1
Else
    Call AccessControl2
End If
If Target.Address = "$C$7" Then
    Call AccountManagement1
Else
    Call AccountManagement2
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: @SilverNak i have included the code thanks in anticipation for your assistance

Comment: @A.eyo - When  `Cell C6` is clicked `Sub AccessControl1()` changes the colour of `Cell E6` to `RGB(154, 205, 50)` but after that `Sub AccountManagement2()` is called and colour of `Cell E6` changes back to `RGB(255, 255, 255)` i.e. `White`. What exactly are you trying?

Comment: @Mrig yes that where am having issues.. its douing that because Accountmanager is overiding that particular cell because both accesscontrol and accountmanagement have E6 in common.. i just want when i click on C6 accesscontrol1() including the color of CellE6 to display

Comment: @Mrig is there a way you could help in tackling this issue

Comment: You'll have to explain when do you want `Sub AccessControl1()`, `Sub AccessControl2()`, `Sub AccountManagement1()` and `Sub AccountManagement1()` to be executed.

Comment: @Mrig you know Cell E6 is common in both Sub AccessControl1(), and Sub AccountManagement1() i would love that particular cell to display at all times when clicked on either C6 or C7

Comment: So if I am right, on clicking `Cell E6` `Call AccessControl1` alone should be executed and when `Cell C7` is clicked you want `Call AccessControl2` followed by `AccountManagement` to be execute. Am I right?

Comment: @Mrig So if I am right, on clicking Cell C6 Call AccessControl1 alone should be executed and when Cell C7 is clicked you want Call AccessControl2 followed by AccountManagement1 to be execute. Am I right? – Yes you are

Comment: @A.eyo - See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment

> on clicking Cell C6 Call AccessControl1 alone should be executed and when Cell C7 is clicked you want Call AccessControl2 followed by AccountManagement1 to be execute. Am I right? – Yes

Change your `Worksheet_SelectionChange` to the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Target.Address = "$C$6" Then
        Call AccessControl1
    ElseIf Target.Address = "$C$7" Then
        Call AccessControl2
        Call AccountManagement1
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much but theres just this slight issue  1) when i tried to click on C6 again C7 remained constant

Comment: @A.eyo - What's the issue?

Comment: when i clicked on C6 it still did not show me the Cell E6 plus when i clicked backwards meanining ( click C6, Click C7 then click C6 again) noticed all of C7 colours where just there... normaly its suppose to return to white.. Default which is Accountmanagement2()..

Comment: i dont know plus you know its just only two cells(C6 and C7) with 4 macros(accesscontrol1() accesscontrol2() Accountmanagement1 Accountmanagement2() Imagine having more than a hundred cells to click and a hundred * 2 Macros... whats your advice?

Comment: @A.eyo - Can you please explain a bit what exactly you want to do on clicking `Cell C6`, `Cell C7` and any other cell.

Comment: Cell C6, C7, C8, C9 C10 are named respectively Accesscontrol and account manager Fire extinguisher, Intrusion Detection and Intrusion Prevention

Comment: @Mirag Its about Mapping i have this Cells namely Cell C6, C7, C8, C9 C10 are named respectively Accesscontrol and account manager Fire extinguisher, Intrusion Detection and Intrusion Prevention. I ham mapping them to various Companies onCell E6, G10, H11, F9 etc with names on the cells like chevron, Exonmobile, Total, Reds and greens etc.... now if i click on C6, all the companies that have thesecurity stuff will be coloured, meanining E6, G10 H11 F9 etc that is mapped to C6 will be coloured , while other companies Cells that dont have Accesscontrol will be white